# Inspect a request when using testing Django rest_framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a test failing in my Django rest_framework project, claiming no authentication credentials were provided, when I'm fairly certain they were. In order to really determine, I'd like to see the actual raw request being produced. Is there a way to inspect the request itself to be sure it is constructed as expected?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, but out of curiosity, authentication failed due to 'login_required' or some other similar django rest_framework decorator?

Comment: Hi, one thing you can try, for testing purpose remove the authentication portion so that your request goes inside the django api method, then use '.stream' of the request. 
Link: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/ (search for .stream)
I have not tried this myself but probably this will give you what you need.

Comment: I use Postman app to construct requests. To debug Django you can put a ipdb in the code that handles the authentication.

Comment: you can use debug in pycharm or you can use print statements to inspect a request....